# Can't get Log4Net to work in our WCF application

Tags: c#, iis-6, web-config, log4net

We are trying to use Log4Net to log from our IIS 6-deployed WCF Application.  We are trying to log to a file, but can't seem to get the log files to be created, let alone see the logging output in them.  The pertinent pieces of out web.config are:

```
<sectionGroup name="common">
    <section name="logging" type="Common.Logging.ConfigurationSectionHandler, Common.Logging" />
</sectionGroup>
...
<common>
    <logging>
        <factoryAdapter type="Common.Logging.Simple.TraceLoggerFactoryAdapter, Common.Logging">
            <arg key="level" value="INFO" />
            <arg key="showLogName" value="true" />
            <arg key="showDataTime" value="true" />
            <arg key="dateTimeFormat" value="yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss:fff" />
        </factoryAdapter>
    </logging>
</common>

<log4net>
    <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="c:\logs\ApplicationInfoTest.log" />
        <threshold value="INFO" />
        <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
        <param name="DatePattern" value="ddMMyyyy" />
        <param name="MaxSizeRollBackups" value="10" />
        <param name="MaximumFileSize" value="10MB" />
        <param name="RollingStyle" value="Size" />
        <param name="StaticLogFileName" value="true" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <param name="Header" value="\r\n\r\n---------------------------------------------\r\n" />
            <param name="Footer" value="\r\n---------------------------------------------\r\n\r\n" />
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="FileAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

With this configuration we can see INFO level logging coming out of our application when using DebugView, but it is clear that this is from the 
    
piece and not the
    
piece.

Is there something that we have failed to set up in web.config?  Is it a permissions issue with the directory we have created for the logs to be written to?

Please point out our obvious mistake.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker How is this the duplicate as it was 2 years before the other one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [ProcessMonitor from SysInternals](http://live.sysinternals.com/tools/procmon.exe) to find out where permissions are being refused

(Potentially you can determine the same info by attaching a debugger and trapping on exceptions, not in Just My Code)

Are you sure that the process under which the service is running has permissions on the folder you're trying to write to?

Comment: Hi Ruben.  Thanks for the input.  The folder (for now, until we get it to work) has "Full Control" permissions for Everyone, ANONYMOUS LOGIN and Administrators users.

Comment: Procmon is the man if there's any confusion - that'll show you which principal is failing to get to do what it wants and where.  Adding the admin users wont help.  Typically the default app pools run as Network service. But you're far better off learning to fish in this case.

Comment: I take it from your desc of the problem that you have definitely hooked up the initialization as the normal logging is happening - you should keep two appenders configured to be sure that it's still just one that's failing.

Comment: Yup, it seems normal logging is fine.  I'll try and find out using Procmon what's going on in Log4Net land...

Answer (score 8):

I have also had to add this line to the AssemblyInfo.cs file of my application in order to get log4net working.

```
// LOG 4 net config
[assembly:log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch=true)]
```

Comment: Surely normal logging wouldnt work then - he's proved that the config isnt the issue?

Comment: Note that you do have to specify this line in the project/dll where you are using log4net the first time. Therefore, I usually take no chances and just add it in all my assemblyInfo.cs's.

Comment: which project do you specifically have to add this line as I have my service implementation in a different project, the WCF host in a different project and a separate project where I do Handle the error..

Comment: You need to add it to the project where you call log4net for the first time.

Answer (score 2):

Try XmlConfigurator.Configure()

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a configuration section configured for log4net? I didn't see that in your code snippet

Answer (score 0):

I would first run the WCF service as a console application - this way you can specify the user account for the application to run as and see if the problem is with your config or with a permissions issue running the service through IIS.

If you are unsure of how to run the service as a console application take a look at http://www.jacopretorius.net/2009/08/running-windows-service-inside-console.html